Deriving Skewness and Kurtosis of a Combined Sequence from the Skewness and Kurtosis of Subsequences
I have a series of $m$ equally-sized subsequences (of numerical values), call them:
$$
X_{1} ... X_{n}\\
X_{n+1} ... X_{2n}\\
...\\
X_{((m-1)n)+1} ... X_{mn}
$$
The mean, standard deviation/variance, skew and kurtosis for each subsequence have already been calculated.
Is there a method to calculate the mean, standard deviation/variance, skew and kurtosis for the combined sequence $X_{1} ... X_{mn}$ solely using the mean, standard deviation/variance, skew and kurtosis of the subsequences (i.e. without having access to the individual $X_{ij}$ values)?
As an illustration, in the case of the mean this is an easy question. Suppose $Y_1$ is the mean of $X_{1} ... X_{n}$, $Y_2$ is the mean of $X_{n+1} ... X_{2n}$, and so on. Then the mean $\bar{Y}$ of the whole sequence $X_{1} ... X_{mn}$ is equal to the mean of the means, i.e. the mean of $Y_{1} ... Y_{m}$.
Likewise it is not difficult to calculate the variance of the whole sequence based on the means and the variances of the subsequences.
How about for skewness and kurtosis?
